# Segurança - O que é uma API KEY?

Tags: api, segurança, api-key

Estou vendo esta palavra em quase todas as aplicações de serviços..

O quê realmente é uma API KEY e quais são os seus usos?

Como ela realmente funciona?

Também por favor, se possível, explicar a diferença entre API KEYs públicas e privadas.

Comment: não tem nada de mais... o nome pode ser “token”, “código”, “id”,  “serial”...  o termo “key” parece mais apropriado então normalmente é o termo que se usa...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

API Keys são credenciais de acesso fornecidas de maneira a autorizar o uso de funcionalidades específicas de uma API. Existem vários tipos de implementações.

- Aplicações web: API Keys podem ser fornecidas como [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](http://rcdevlabs.github.io/2015/02/12/como-criar-uma-api-restfull-em-nodejs-e-autenticar-usando-json-web-token-jwt/) via cookies ou cabeçalhos HTTP; em operações de back-end, [podem ser parte da URI original do request](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).
- Aplicações desktop: API Keys podem ser utilizadas para acessar a funcionalidade de uma biblioteca de terceiros.

O sentido de chave de API pública ou privada também depende da implementação. Por exemplo, você pode possuir uma chave pública emitida para seu cliente (digamos www.app.com) que permite o acesso a uma API específica (api.servico.com), que é então utilizada pelo seu browser. Entretanto chamadas de servidor para servidor utilizam uma outra chave, privada, para operações mais sensitivas como autenticação e validação de credenciais.

Answer (score 8):

## API

Basicamente uma API é um conjunto de rotinas e padrões de programação para acesso a uma aplicação de software ou plataforma baseado na Web. A sigla API refere-se ao termo em inglês "Application Programming Interface" que significa "Interface de Programação de Aplicativos" traduzindo para o português.

Geralmente API é desenvolvida quando uma empresa de software tem a intenção de que outros criadores de software desenvolvam produtos associados ao seu serviço. Existem várias empreas que disponibilizam seus códigos e instruções para serem usados em outros sites da maneira mais conveniente para seus usuários. Existe o Youtube, Google Maps, Facebook, Twitter; que são grandes exemplos na área de APIs. Por meio de seu código original, muitos outros sites e aplicações utilizam os dados adaptando-o da melhor forma a fim de utilizar esses serviços.

#### Porque expor os dados?

Por alguns motivos específicos, expor certos dados e recursos é uma estratégia de negócios e inovação muito bem pensada. É importante pensar em alguns motivos para essa exposição de dados. Mantenha esses aspectos em mente:

- Integrar sua plataforma à parceiros;
  Gerar inovação sobre seus próprios dados, de uma maneira que não poderia sozinho;
- Gerar desenvolvimento de sua própria plataforma em novos meios;
  Gerar mais mercado e expandir o público-alvo;
- Organização do setor de TI, em que os consumidores das APIs são as outras equipes internas da empresa, e as APIs expostas funcionam como portais de troca de dados entre setores.
- Portanto, a API é uma interface para os ativos (dados) da empresa, mas que ao mesmo tempo barra usos abusivos desses ativos.

## Key

Da tradução livre do inglês, "Chave". Referênte ao significado do português temos, que é utensílio de metal que se introduz na fechadura à qual pertence para movimentar a lingueta, e que possibilita abrir ou cerrar portas, tampas, cadeados etc.

Considerando isso, a **API KEY**, esta muitas vezes atua como um identificador único e uma **chave secreta** para autenticação, e geralmente têm um conjunto de direitos de acesso à **API** associada a ele. Uma API KEY pode ser baseado no sistema UUID é a sigla em ingês para Universally unique identifier, que traduzindo para o português fica Identificador Único Universal, para garantir que será única para cada utilizador. É bem simples de compreender pois o nome auto-explicativo, mas o conceito do UUID é algo mais complexo e muito funcional.

No caso do Google Map, a sua 'API KEY' é baseada em um formulário curto do certificado digital do seu aplicativo, conhecido como impressão digital **[SHA-1](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3143/metodo-sha1.aspx)**. Para exibir a impressão digital **SHA-1** do seu certificado, primeiro certifique-se de estar usando o certificado correto, sendo um certificado de depuração e de publicação.

> Mantenha sua chave secreta e tokens de acesso privados. Você pode
>   compartilhá-los com um agente que está operando em seu aplicativo, se
>   ele assinar um acordo de confidencialidade.

A API KEY do Facebook é uma seqüência de números gerados aleatoriamente que cria cada vez que uma pessoa registrar seu aplicativo através do site. Sempre totalmente numérica na natureza e é composto por 15 caracteres. Mas é somente para este caso, pois cada empresa tem sua política para criação das chaves, sendo numéricas, apenas letras, etc.

Chaves de API permitem gerar uma credencial de autenticação que é separado do seu nome de usuário e senha em alguns casos. Deve-se criar chaves de API exclusivas para cada uma de suas aplicações ou servidores de modo que possa facilmente revogá-las sem interromper outros sistemas, se necessário.

#### Mais detalhes

- [O que é API?](http://canaltech.com.br/o-que-e/software/o-que-e-api/)
- [UUID - Identificador Único Universal](http://jaydson.org/uuid-identificador-unico-universal/)
- [Inscrição e chave de API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)
- [API Keys](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/api_keys.html)
- [Política da Plataforma do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/?locale=pt_BR)

Answer (score 4):

Essa é uma pergunta muito ampla...

A função exata de uma API key depende bastante da entidade que a gerou e com qual intuito.

Geralmente, uma API KEY é o nome que se dá para uma token secreto que é enviado dentro de uma *request* para um *webservice*, de forma a identificar e muitas vezes autenticar o usuário que está chamando o serviço.

A chave também pode ser incluída como parte de uma assinatura da *request* inteira de forma a verificar o seu conteúdo e prevenir ataques como *[replay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)* e *[man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)*

Além disso, nos casos em que você precisa autenticar o usuário antes que ele possa acessar um recurso de seu webservice, há uma grande vantagem de se usar uma API KEY. Esse tipo de chave/token viabiliza uma forma de autenticação [stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) em que você não precisa criar sessões, fazer uso de cookies ou qualquer outro estado condicional/temporário que exigiriam chamadas adicionais e mecanismos de controle de sessão.

Por outro lado, se você tem um par de chaves (pública e privada) então estamos falando de alguma forma de [criptografia assimétrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). As técnicas que envolvem esse tipo de criptografia são mais complexas e mais seguras para identificar positivamente a origem e a autenticidade de uma mensagem, ao mesmo tempo que a protege de alterações.

Comment: desculpe pelos links em inglês, mas acredito que você pode acessar a versão em português pela própria wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

**API Keys**, como já foi [dito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149220/51124), são credenciais de acesso fornecidas de maneira a autorizar o uso de funcionalidades específicas de uma API e são usadas ​​para monitorar e controlar a forma como a API está sendo utilizada, por exemplo, para evitar o uso indevido ou abuso do API.

API Keys permitem gerar uma credencial de autenticação que é separado do seu nome de usuário e senha. Eles são independentes um do outro e são facilmente descartáveis. Você deve criar única API Key para cada um de seus aplicativos ou servidores de modo que você pode facilmente revogá-las sem interromper outros sistemas, se necessário.

Nesse [site](https://stormpath.com/blog/top-six-reasons-use-api-keys-and-how), em inglês, mostra as top 6 razões para usar uma API key e como usá-las.

API pública, como o próprio nome diz, esta chave é pública e pode ser visto por qualquer pessoa, que não compromete a segurança das informações. Já a privada deve ser mantida completamente privada e segura, pois com ela podem ser feitas consultas que comprometem a segurança. Depende da implementação.

Referências:

- [¿Qué son las API Keys?](https://www.conekta.io/es/ayuda/preguntas/que-son-las-api-keys)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key)
- [API Keys](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/api_keys.html)